# Heavy download folder, but its empty

Tags: hard-drive, space

MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015) running High Sierra 10.13.6:

I'm trying to make space on my mac, and I found out that my download folder is 30GB heavy but there is nothing in it... What can I do?

Comment: In Terminal, what's the output of: `du -ch ~/Downloads`

Comment: Is your Download folder a link to another folder on a different  drive perhaps?

Comment: You may also try `ls -a ~/Downloads` in the terminal to list `all` files - trying to make sure there aren't any hidden files in there

Comment: Have you emptied the Trash?